# Spinner in action bar with only icon but not the selected option

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

I am working on a app with action bar for navigation. Now I am trying to add a `Spinner` to the `ActionBar`.

I am able to get my custom icon on the `ActionBar`. But when I add entries into the spinner, the icon is hidden behind the selection box with first item selected.

I want to have only the icon in the `ActionBar` and the `drop-down-list/spinner` to appear when tapped on the icon.

This is my code :

```
private void initializeMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);

    View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.menuSort).getActionView();
    Spinner spinner=(Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.bookmarks_menu);

    Bookmark bookmark1 = new Bookmark();
    Bookmark bookmark2 = new Bookmark();

    List<Bookmark> list = new ArrayList<Bookmark>();
    list.add(bookmark1);
    list.add(bookmark2);

    SpinAdapter adapter = new SpinAdapter(getApplicationContext(),0, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 9):

Icon-only `Spinner` is achievable through a few steps.

**Step 1**

Put the icon you want in the xml:

```
<Spinner
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/ic_sort_white_24dp" />
```

**Step 2**

Then, in the `adapter` of the `Spinner`, override `getView()`, like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // this part is needed for hiding the original view
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            return view;
        }
};
```

**Explanation**

We need to understand that `getView()` in the adapter is the view that will be used when the `Spinner` is not opened. We make the visibility `gone` because we don't want to see it, so that what is left is the background of `Spinner` from the xml, which I already set to `ic_sort_white_24dp` in this example (Step 1).

Do not mix up with `getDropDownView()` which is used for the rows of options that will drop downed after the `Spinner` is clicked.

**Bonus Screenshot!**

This is how mine look like. Hope it helps!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter, you need to override getDropDownView().  That should provide the view used in the rows of the spinner.  getView() should then return an ImageView for your icon.

See these 2 answers on similar questions for more details and examples:

- [actionbar spinner customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193598/actionbar-spinner-customisation/15293471#15293471)
- [difference between getview and getdropdownview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433874/difference-between-getview-getdropdownview-in-spinneradapter/13433875#13433875)

Answer (score 0):

check this its working..

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final String[] choices = { "Android", "iOS", "RIM" };
    final int[] choices_img = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ios,
            R.drawable.black };

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                choices);
        ListViewAdapter adapter1 = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter1,
                new OnNavigationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition,
                            long itemId) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                choices[itemPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context con) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return choices.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return product_id1.size();
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return product_id1.get(position).hashCode();
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ListContent holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_row1, null);
                holder = new ListContent();

                holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                holder.img_p = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                // holder.total_rate.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener1);

                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.img_p.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                    choices_img[position]));
            holder.name.setText("" + choices[position]);

            return v;
        }
    }

    static class ListContent {

        ImageView img_p;
        TextView name;

    }

}
```

if you want only icon then just use image view in scan_row1.xml

Comment: Thanks @Dhawal. I managed to get this screen. What I am trying to achieve is to have only an icon on the action bar but not the selected item (rim_icon and the text"RIM). I want the 3 list options to appear on tapping the action bar icon.